# CCLabelTTF enableStroke doesn't work on IOS 7

Tags: cocos2d-x

I tried to enable stroke effect for a CCLabel object (CCLabelTTF::enableStroke). But I find that it only works on IOS 6.x (and previous version.) When I run my game on IOS 7, it doesn't work. Does any  one knows how to fix it on IOS 7?

Cocos2d-x version: 2.1.4.

Comment: This also seems to be the case with cocos2d-iphone

Comment: Check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720431/stroking-not-working-on-cclabelttf-in-cocos2d-x-ios-in-c