# Stroking not working on CCLabelTTF in cocos2d-x ios in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am tryng to make an outline of green color in my label but its not working.. 
my code is

```
CCLabelTTF* pLabel = CCLabelTTF::create("Hello World", "HoboStd", 50);
pLabel->setPosition(ccp(200,200));
pLabel->enableStroke(ccGREEN, 5.0,true);
this->addChild(pLabel);
```

Its not providing the outline around the label text Hello World.Any one here who can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the fix in ios7.0 on how to enable stroking on labels
The normal stroking code of a label doesn’t work in IOS 7.0 but it works successfuly below IOS 7.0
The basic code for enabling stroking is provided below. We need to add a CCLabelTTF and then call the enableStroke function

```
CCLabelTTF *label=CCLabelTTF::create("Hello", "Arial.fnt", 50);
label->setPosition(ccp(300,300));
label->enableStroke(ccGREEN, 1.0,true);
this->addChild(label);
```

This works fine with IOS below 7.0. But in IOS 7.0 there is no stroking effect on the label. In order to fix the issue just follow some steps

## Step1

Find the CCImage.mm file in your project and find the following code written there

```
//actually draw the text in the context
//XXX: ios7 casting
[str drawInRect:CGRectMake(textOriginX, textOrigingY, textWidth, textHeight) withFont:font   
lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:(NSTextAlignment)align];
```

## Step2

Now add the following code just below this line

```
//New Code Start
if(pInfo->hasStroke)
{
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextStroke);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, pInfo->strokeColorR, pInfo->strokeColorG, pInfo->strokeColorB,  
1);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, pInfo->strokeSize);
    [str drawInRect:CGRectMake(textOriginX, textOrigingY, textWidth, textHeight) withFont:font   
lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:(NSTextAlignment)align];
}
//New Code End
```

Save the CCImage.mm file and then again re-run your project. It will redraw stroke with correct color.Tested on 7.0 simulator

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and I get the outline. Try to reduce the stroke width to 1.0.

```
pLabel->enableStroke(ccGREEN, 1.0,true);
```

Comment: With a 5 pixels stoke width it's no more possible to distinct the stroke from the text [screenshot](http://i58.tinypic.com/25ktx5k.png)

Comment: Seems you found a bug. You should probably open a bug report [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/native/issues/new)

Comment: i have googled a lot..i found everywhere that stroking problem is there in ios7.0 but below 7.0 everything is fine